# xpath not working for UFT14 getting Failed to run the test due to an unknown error

Tags: hp-uft, uft14

I am trying to run the following code.

```
SystemUtil.Run "Chrome.exe","https://www.mortgagecalculator.org/"
val = Browser(MortCalPage).Page(MortCalPage).WebElement("xpath:=//DIV/DIV/H3\[normalize-space\(\)=""\$.*").GetROProperty ("outertext")
```

**But i am either getting "Failed to run the test due to an unknown error." or unable to find object error**

Used a reg exp for xpath

Original Value of xpath after obj identification:

```
"xpath:=//DIV/DIV/H3\[normalize-space\(\)=""\$1,401\.63""\]"
```

Value of xpath after using reg ex:

```
"xpath:=//DIV/DIV/H3\[normalize-space\(\).*"
```

Comment: Please first verify that the problem is in the XPath part. Try `Browser(MortCalPage).Hightlight` and then `Browser(MortCalPage).Page(MortCalPage).Highlight`.

Comment: Few things going on there. You can't (easily) regex an xpath. You don't escape the characters in the xpath. Your quotation  characters are in a bit of a mix. Try .WebElement("xpath:=//DIV/DIV/H3[normalize-space()='$1,401.63']", "index:=0"). -  that assumes your xpath actually works.  If you describe what you're trying to achieve with some information from you dom I'll be able to provide much more detail